# Threading Behaviour of NSURLSessionTasks from Multiple NSURLSessions?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Say I have 5 NSURLSessions and I create an NSURLSessionDownloadTask under each one. I then start each task running in a for loop.

How does the threading behave for the request ? Are they executed async individually, or would they be processed serially ?

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: Thanks Rob - great idea.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest using a single `NSURLSession` object for multiple downloads, as there's some overhead of having multiple session objects. It probably isn't material with only five downloads, but if the number of downloads increases dramatically, you'll see some memory impact. Also, with a single `NSURLSession`, you can specify a [`HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost) for your `NSURLSessionConfiguration`

Comment: Thanks Rob - problem is that all the requests have different HTTP headers so need different NSURLSessionConfigurations.

Comment: OK. Obviously, you can also generally specify headers at the request, too, but it doesn't sound like you have so many downloads that it's that critical.

Comment: Rob thanks - worked out how to set headers at request now - moved to one session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be processed concurrently. You can verify this by specifying a delegate for the sessions and log the progress in [`downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate/URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:).